# PHP Split and store data

Tags: php, split

```
[{"id":123456,"name":"Super IT Store","date":"2021-02-08"},{"id":123457,"name":"Duper IT Store","date":"2021-02-08"}]
```

Good day! How can I split the data above and store it into respective array and eliminate the punctuation?

Example output needed:

```
id[0] = 123456

id[1] = 123457

name[0] = "Super IT Store"

name[1] = "Duper IT Store"
```

I have tried to use `preg_match_all` but it seems weird to extract this kind of data because the actual data could be longer than this a lot.

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far. [edit]

Comment: It looks like JSON data to me so I would try json_decode and see what you get https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: I extracted the data from the live endpoint given by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will solve your problem

```php
<?php

$json = '[{"id":123456,"name":"Super IT Store","date":"2021-02-08"},{"id":123457,"name":"Duper IT Store","date":"2021-02-08"}]';
$elements = json_decode($json);

$ids   = [];
$names = [];

foreach ($elements as $index => $element) {
    $element       = (array) $element;
    $ids[$index]   = $element['id'];
    $names[$index] = $element['name'];
}

print_r($ids);
print_r($names);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => 123457
)
Array
(
    [0] => Super IT Store
    [1] => Duper IT Store
)
```

First I use `json_decode` to decode the json and then in the foreach I use this `$element       = (array) $element;` to convert the `stdclass object` to array and then I can work with it